# cocos2d replaceScene with CCTransitionSlideInL has no effect

Tags: replace, cocos2d-iphone, transition

Recently,I have to implement paging functions with cocos2d using transition of CCTransitionSlideInL.But there is no effect.I tried some effects,and surprised to find that only transitions of CCTransitionSplitCols and CCTransitionSplitRows effect,others not.Followed is my code.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSlideInL transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:scene]];
```

I would be very grateful if someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please post the code that creates your `CCScene` object (variable scene).

Comment: CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
[scene addChild:layer];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSlideInL transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:scene]]; Could you please help me?I am very busy with this problem.

Comment: I am very anxious with this problem.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What does "does not work" mean in your case?

The code you have written works perfectly. If "does not work" means nothing happens then the issue is likely in how your layer is created. I suspect the layer variable is invalid. If you want help on that, post your layer creation code.

Comment: I said "does not work" means that the scene changed successfully,but without effect of slide.Followed is my code.`CCDraftLayer *layer = [[CCDraftLayer alloc] init];
    [self setCurDraftLayer:layer];
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSplitCols transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:scene]];
    [layer release];`(CCDraftLayer inherites from CCLayer)

Comment: Can you help me with this problem?Thanks a lot.@ Pinwheeler

Comment: I was unable to replicate the error. I might even recommend re-installing cocos2d. The transition works fine for me according to all of the information you've given me so far

Comment: Thanks,buddy.I will try to re-installing cocos2d.@ Pinwheeler

Comment: So,finally I solved it myself.That is because the transition of CCTransitionSlideInL must collide with the method of draw that CCLayer supports.More specifically，it collides with CCRenderTexture I used in the method.

Answer (score 0):

So,finally I solved it myself.That is because the transition of CCTransitionSlideInL must collide with the method of draw that CCLayer supports.More specifically，it collides with CCRenderTexture I used in the method.